# Python selenium: Scrolling inside iframe

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, iframe

[image: Trying to scroll tab 4.]

Hi, I am able to switch between tabs, access all elements. I am unable to scroll in this iframe. Script executes without error. But scrolling is not happening. Please help. Code I am using is as follows.

```
    # switching to iframe
    iframe = self.browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
    self.browser.switch_to_frame(iframe)
    time.sleep(1)

    #clicking tab 4
    self.force_click('xpath=/html/body/div/md-content/md-tabs/md-tabs-wrapper/md-tabs-canvas/md-pagination-wrapper/md-tab-item[4]/span')
    time.sleep(4)

    #scrolling
    elm = self.browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('html')
    elm[0].send_keys(Keys.END)
```

HTML of the iframe is as follows.

```
<iframe id="widget-iframe" class="widget-iframe" frameborder="0" ap-onunload="vm.onFrameUnload()" ap-onload="vm.onFrameLoad()" ng-src="/apps/launchpad-view-widget/" src="/apps/launchpad-view-widget/">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html class="ng-scope" ng-app="launchpadViewWidget">
     <head>
     <body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Can you try javascript scroll after switching to that iframe

Comment: please provide the script i need try using java script.

Comment: this scrolls down to the bottom of the page-> driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

Comment: I tried this, but its not working. passing without any error, but not scrolling.

Comment: Can you check this, replace the id with the element that you need to scroll to view->element = driver.find_element_by_id('some_id')
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view

Comment: Is there anyway, i can get complete html page source(including parts which is hidden in current window) without scrolling?

Comment: Its an angular app, so html will be visible dynamically. I suggest we can use Actions class to drag and drop the scroll bar of that iframe

Comment: I wouldn't knew the element i want to scroll to, as i dont know the elements. I just wanted to scroll until the end of the table.

Comment: Drag and Drop in Actions class might work

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to set window size bigger, so you wont have to scroll

```
self.browser.set_window_size(1920,1080)#(4096, 3112) <-4k resolution(if needed)
```

--
Edit:

Also can get the HTML code from browser and manage it with BeautifulSoup

```
html_source = browser.page_source
```

For python2.x i recomend

```
html_source = browser.page_source.encode('utf-8')
```

Then find the table that you want without care about scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, this works as of now. But I am worried if my table size goes beyond the 4k limit, it may again miss the rows.

Comment: Is there anyway, i can get complete html page source(including parts which is hidden in current window) without scrolling?

Comment: @unnikrishnan.v Edited my answer.

Comment: when i am using html_source = browser.page_source, i am not getting the html for rows, which are not visible in the current window (to get html for those rows, i need to scroll.)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before.  I couldn't see the values past the scroll area.  The solution was to get the javascript object that populates the table via JSON.  You can do this using the javascriptexecutor:  `driver.execute_script`

Hope that helps!